# Where can I find the file 'DotfuscatorCE_5.0.2500.msi'?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to install the Service Pack 1 update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. However, it cannot locate the file `DotfuscatorCE_5.0.2500.msi`

Does anyone know where I can find/download this file?

Error message:

> The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is
>   unavailable.
>
> Click OK to try again, or enter an alternate path
>   to a folder containing the installation package
>   'DotfuscatorCE_5.0.2500.msi' in the box below.

OS: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

Comment: Can you post the whole error message and what operating system you are using

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response, but I've updated the info.

Answer (score 8):

I have had this issue before, One thing i tried is installing the updates via an [iso file](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=210710). This allowed me to extract "DotfuscatorCE_5.0.2500.msi"

Once you mount the DVD ISO image file (e.g. with a free tool like [Virtual Clone Drive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html)) you will find the file in the ISO image \Dotfuscator folder.

Once you supply the Dotfuscator you may also find the update wants subsequent files. Take the same approach for any other missing setup files. They are all on the DVD ISO image.

### Examples on ISO:

- \Dotfuscator\DotfuscatorCE_5.0.2500.msi
- \Fsharp\FSharpRedist2.0.msi
- \SpTools\SpTools_x86_enu.msi

Comment: +1: This saved the day (and was the earliest correct answer). Many thanks

Comment: In case anyone else runs into this -- I had to copy the Dotfuscator msi package somewhere other than its location in the ISO directory to get it to install. For some reason it does not like being run from a virtual ISO...

Answer (score 2):

Try offline installation.

[Visual Studio 2010 ISO file](http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/B/A/EBA0A152-F426-47E6-9E3F-EFB686E3CA20/VS2010SP1dvd1.iso)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the install from a network share? Try copying it to your local machine first if that's the case.

You can also try deleting the installer class if there is cruft left in the registry. Backup the registry first, then delete the key at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\0BC19BFC9D71BE44FB2B3570BAE7D7CD
```

Comment: No, I downloaded it from the microsoft website. Also, I have no idea how to work in the registry..

Comment: @James type `regedit` in the start menu/run box and hit enter. Navigate the tree view to the above location and remove the key starting with 0BC19..

Comment: What will that do?